# Use PHP or MySQL to remove duplicates on large lists?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an HTML textarea that my users can use to paste thousands of e-mail addresses.  If I want to eliminate the duplicate e-mail addresses from the textarea, is it less costly to:

1. Insert all of the e-mail addresses into a MySQL database and perform a `SELECT DISTINCT` Query
2. Load all e-mail addresses into a PHP array and perform `array_unique()`?

Thanks!

Comment: With only thousands of addresses, it most likely won't matter.

Comment: @Pekka웃 still, i find it intersting, what about 50,000 or 1 million?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use a MySQL `UNIQUE` constraint for the e-mail addresses? http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp That way, if you insert an e-mail that already exists, it should be ommited.

Comment: It's not a question that can be universally answered without more details.

Comment: What other details? Let's pretend that it could be 50,000 to 1 million addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is less costly to : Load all e-mail addresses into a PHP array and perform `array_unique()` .

Considered `20,000` random strings of `10` chars in length each .

( In those `20,000` random strings , `16,384` are unique strings )

`Test #1 :`
Declared an array with those `20,000` random strings
Ran `array_unique` on the above array
Execution duration : `0.141`39604568481 Secs

`Test #2 :`
Declared an array with those `20,000` random strings
Inserted `20,000` random strings in database table using PDO prepared statement
Retrieved DISTINCT random strings from the table
Execution duration : `735.758`27002525 Secs

> Even before the info is sent to the server you could try to remove the duplicates from the textarea on the `user-end` ( using Javascript , etc ) .
>  Then you can also use `array_unique` on the `server-end` to make sure there are no duplicates .

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to handle this on a per-request basis rather than insert arbitrary records into to a MySQL table. If you insert each record into a table without knowing if it will be a duplicate you will ultimately end up having to write a script to delete the duplicates.

For example:

Lets say your text area contains a comma separated list of emails in a POST request

```
$emails = $_POST['email'];
// in real life you will want to validate each string with a regex
$emails = preg_split('/,/', $emails);
// or you could do explode(",", $emails);

// acknowledge possession of an array
$unique_emails = array();

foreach($emails as $key => $value)
{
  $unique_emails[$value] = $value;
}

// unique_emails contains all unique addresses.
```

Now you can insert these into the table without having to worry about non-unique records.

Comment: I guess you mean `preg_split`

Comment: Yes sir. I did mean `preg_split`

Answer (score 0):

It's better to handle the situation in a PHP way.

If you **don't need the duplicates** then why should you stuff the database with **unnecessary data**?

In addition to that say already the table contains some redundant records. So each time you enter redundant records without filtering, the table size increases and thus the `select distinct` operation becomes **more time-complex**. So it is certainly better if you handle the redundancy of records in the server-side itself before those get inserted in the database.

Moreover, as both the ways you have specified are **`time-complex`** its better not to make it **`space-complex`** too.

Comment: I have to disagree. I think it's better to handle database consistency and duplicates from the database itself.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I sounded rude. What I meant is that is better to always configure the database to manage this kind of rules, that will ensure its consistency in a long-term basis. There's no point in handling the situation using PHP when the database already gives you choices like the `UNIQUE` constraint. A matter of opinion, I think. Good luck!

Comment: @AlejandroIván Yes that is another way out.

Comment: @AlejandroIván I voted your comment to the question. your answer is a really good option.